# Add ": " for every nth character in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

Say i have this:

```
x = ["hello-543hello-454hello-765", "hello-745hello-635hello-321"]
```

how can i get the output to:

```
["hello-543: hello-454: hello-765", "hello-745: hello-635: hello-321"]
```

Comment: What are the rules in which you get from the input to the output? What have you tried? what errors are you getting?

Comment: Do you have a more practical example or will you have repeating words in the actual list? A fix I have won't work if all words are not the same.

Comment: They all will have the same character length but different characters, I created a better example above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split each string based on substring length with a list comprehension using `range` where the step value is the number of characters each substring should contain. Then use `join` to convert each list back to a string with the desired separator characters.

```
x = ["hello-543hello-454hello-765", "hello-745hello-635hello-321"]

n = 9
result = [': '.join([s[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(s), n)]) for s in x]
print(result)
# ['hello-543: hello-454: hello-765', 'hello-745: hello-635: hello-321']
```

Or with [`textwrap.wrap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.wrap):

```
from textwrap import wrap

x = ["hello-543hello-454hello-765", "hello-745hello-635hello-321"]

n = 9
result = [': '.join(wrap(s, n)) for s in x]
print(result)
# ['hello-543: hello-454: hello-765', 'hello-745: hello-635: hello-321']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure every `str` length is multiply of your `n`, I would use `re.findall` for that task.

```
import re
txt1 = "hello-543hello-454hello-765"
txt2 = "hello-745hello-635hello-321"
out1 = ": ".join(re.findall(r'.{9}',txt1))
out2 = ": ".join(re.findall(r'.{9}',txt2))
print(out1) #hello-543: hello-454: hello-765
print(out2) #hello-745: hello-635: hello-321
```

`.{9}` in `re.findall` mean `9` of any characters excluding newline (`\n`), so this code would work properly as long as your `str`s do not contain `\n`. If this does not hold true you need to add `re.DOTALL` as third argument of `re.findall`